# How can I create a BindingConverter that allows me to drop the View parameter of a click listener on Android?

Tags: android, android-databinding

I've got a lot of methods with this signature:

```
public void onButtonClick(View view) {
 
}
```

Most of the time I don't need the `view` parameter, and AS gives me an unused method property warning.

*Desired solution*: A `@BindingConverter` for Android Databinding that translates a function with no parameters to a `View.ClickListener`.

I've tried this but it fails compile-time stating it doesn't match the method signature. Why?

```
public interface MyAction {
    void act();
}

@BindingConversion
public static View.OnClickListener convertaroony(final MyAction action) {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            action.act();
        }
    };
}
  
<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Clicky"
        android:onClick="@{activity::onButtonClick}"/>

public class JavaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void onButtonClick() {
        Log.i("JAVA", "I got a click, sir!");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Name of the method in this View's context to invoke when the view is clicked. This name must correspond to a public method that takes exactly one parameter of type View. For instance, if you specify `android:onClick="sayHello"`, you must declare a `public void sayHello(View v)` method of your context (typically, your Activity). --> `<attr name="onClick" format="string" />`

In `public void sayHello(View v)`, view `v` is the one you apply your custom onClick method just like

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        
        }
```

**NOTE**: You can find that same description by jumping to the source of `android:onClick`.

Comment: I don't see how this answers my question. My desired solution is to have a method in the Activity that does _not_ take a View parameter, and I believe that should be possible with Android Databinding Converters